# How to insert a background image in JfreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I need to insert a background image for my graphic. Actually, I did it, but I have problem.

How to remove everything except the red line itself?

Now I have this result(look below image).

[image]

```
XYSeries series4 = new XYSeries("Траектория движения ЛА");
for (int i = 0; i < La.size(); i++) {
    series4.add(massLatitude[i], massLongitude[i]);

}
XYSeriesCollection seriesCollection4 = new XYSeriesCollection(series4);
Image icon = ImageIO.read(new File("image.jpg"));
final JFreeChart chart4 = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot("Траектория полета ЛА", null, null,
    seriesCollection4);
chart4.setBackgroundImage(icon);
final ChartPanel chartPanel4 = new ChartPanel(chart4);
chartPanel4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1300, 480));
panel.add(chartPanel4);
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to remove everything except the red line itself?

You need to get rid of the grid lines, and the *plot* background (different from the chart background):

```
chart.getXYPlot().setDomainGridlinesVisible(false);
chart.getXYPlot().setRangeGridlinesVisible(false);
Color trans = new Color(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0);
chart.getPlot().setBackgroundPaint( trans );
```

Comment: getPlot () does not have the setDomainGridlinesVisible and setRangeGridlinesVisibley method. These methods are in getXYPlot, but if I call them from getXYPlot nothing changes. The second part of your advice helped me)

Comment: @VIRICH Does `.setDomainGridlinePaint();` work, if you pass the transparent color to that?

Answer (score 0):

I achieved success by half) But how can I remove the notation XAxis and YAxis? Now I have it [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIg6U.png)

```
XYSeries series4 = new XYSeries("Траектория движения ЛА");
        for (int i = 0; i < La.size(); i++) {
            series4.add(massLongitude[i], massLatitude[i]);

        }
        XYSeriesCollection seriesCollection4 = new XYSeriesCollection(series4);
        Image icon = ImageIO.read(new File("DlyaOpen.jpg"));
        final JFreeChart chart4 = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot(null, null, null,
                seriesCollection4);
        chart4.removeLegend();
        chart4.setBackgroundImage(icon);
        Color trans = new Color(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0);
        chart4.getPlot().setBackgroundPaint( trans );
        chart4.getPlot().setOutlineVisible(false);
        chart4.getXYPlot().setRangeGridlinesVisible(false);
        chart4.getXYPlot().setDomainGridlinesVisible(false);
        final ChartPanel chartPanel4 = new ChartPanel(chart4);
        chartPanel4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 480));
        panel.add(chartPanel4);
```